# Identity Server 4 Equivalent to Identity Server 3 IUserService AuthenticateExternalAsync and AuthenticateLocalAsync methods

Tags: authentication

I am working on finding equivalent Identity Server 3 IUserService functionality in Identity Server 4. The recommended path seems to be to use 'IProfileService' and 'IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.  However, 'IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator' does not appear to work for Implicit and other standard work flows.  Is there an alternative?

I have been reading the documents and so far, I have not come up with the Identity Server 4 equivalent of IUserService's AuthenticateExternalAsync and AuthenticateLocalAsync methods.

Comment: For anyone else strugging with this, you are on your own for this type of functionality (see this post - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3983).  What we are doing is (some details are in the github post) is creating our own IUserService with the same method signature (note that parameters will change since they are Identity Server 3 models) and injecting it into our AccountController.  The only thing I do not know yet is how to handle 'AuthenticateExternalAsync'.

Comment: Our solution will (likely) look like this:

Comment: public interface INewUserService
{
Task AuthenticateExternalAsync(<new parameter(s) here!>);
Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(<new parameter(s) here!>);
Task SignOutAsync(<new parameter(s) here!>);
}

Comment: Once inside our account controller, they will be called from these methods - 
-AuthenticateLocalAsync(args) from '[HttpPost] -> Task Login(LoginInputModel model)'
-SignOutAsync(<new parameter(s) here!>) from '[HttpPost] -> Task Logout(LogoutInputModel model)'

Comment: Once I have fully vetted a solution, I will post an answer.  I hope this helps folks :)